# Enlazar imagen de Slick Slider con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentado utilizar [Slick Slider Js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) para mostrar un Slider de Productos, quisiera que al darle click a las imagenes estas me redireccione a un URL especifico.

He visto esta pregunta relacionada pero sigo sin entender porque no me identifica el href.
[JQuery identificar href en div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855624/jquery-how-to-set-click-on-href-in-the-div).

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h2,
p {
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}



.slider {
    max-width: 8000px;
    width: 115%;
    margin: 15px auto;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    /* box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26); */
    /*h v b s*/
}

.slick-slider button {
    display: none !important;
}

.slick-slide {
    color: #333;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-slide .desc {
    opacity: 0;
    margin: -20px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.slick-slide .desc>* {
    transition: all 900ms ease;
}

.slick-slide .desc h2 {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size:25px;
}

.slick-slide .desc p {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;
}

.slick-dots {
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-dots li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active {
    background: var(--yellow-color);
}

.slick-dots button {
    display: none;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
    /* background: blue;*/
}

.slick-slide {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.slick-current {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.slick-current .desc {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slick-current .desc h2 {
    left: 0;
}

.slick-current .desc p {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

.mybtn {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 4px solid #18c495;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #18c495;
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: initial;
}

.mybtn-preview01 {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 4px solid var(--blue-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--blue-color);
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: initial;
    font-family: 'KGBSpace';
}

.mybtn-preview02 {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 4px solid var(--sweet-potato-bg);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--sweet-potato-bg);
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: initial;
    font-family: 'KGBSpace';
}

.mybtn-preview03 {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 4px solid var(--red-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--red-color);
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: initial;
    font-family: 'KGBSpace';
}

.mybtn-preview04 {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 4px solid var(--purple-sweetBTN-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--purple-sweetBTN-color);
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: initial;
    font-family: 'KGBSpace';
}


@media(max-width:1366px) {
    .slider {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media(max-width:720px){
    .slick-slide .desc h2{
        font-size:21px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:720px){
    .mybtn-preview04{
        font-size: .5em;
    }
    .mybtn-preview03{
        font-size: .5em;
    }
    .mybtn-preview02{
        font-size: .5em;
    }
    .mybtn-preview01{
        font-size: .5em;
    }
    .mybtn{
         font-size: .5em;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css">


<section class="slider">

  <div id="product1">
    <a href="products/newURL.html">
      <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/b5355/304/Scenery_Sunrises_and_sunsets_Fields_Sky_Sun_519151_600x800.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">
      <h2 style="color:var(--blue-color)">Product1</h2>
      <a href="#" class="mybtn-preview01">View Product</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="product2">
    <a href="products/newURL.html">
      <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/b5355/304/Scenery_Sunrises_and_sunsets_Fields_Sky_Sun_519151_600x800.jpg">
    </a>

    <div class="desc">
      <h2 style="color:var(--sweet-potato-bg)">Product2</h2>
      <a href="#" class="mybtn-preview02">View Product</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="product3">
    <a href="products/newURL.html">
      <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/b5355/304/Scenery_Sunrises_and_sunsets_Fields_Sky_Sun_519151_600x800.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">
      <h2 style="color:var(--red-color)">Product3</h2>
      <a href="#" class="mybtn-preview03">View Product</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="product4">
    <a href="products/newURL.html">
      <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/b5355/304/Scenery_Sunrises_and_sunsets_Fields_Sky_Sun_519151_600x800.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">
      <h2 style="color:var(--red-color)">Product4</h2>
      <a href="#" class="mybtn-preview03">View Product</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#product1 a").click(function(event) {
      var link = $(this).attr("href");
      $("#product1").load(link);
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#product2 a").click(function() {
      var link = $(this).attr("href");
      $("#product2").load(link);
      return false;
    });
  });

</script>


<script>
  function createSlick() {

    $(".slider").not('.slick-initialized').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      autoplay: true,
      dots: false,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      pauseOnFocus: false,

      slidesToShow: 3,
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          dots: false,
          arrows: false,
          infinite: false,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }]
    });

  }

  createSlick();

  $(window).on('resize', createSlick);

</script>
```

He probado esta respuesta con JQuery pero al presionar la imagen no me hace ningún efecto.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#product1 a").click(function(event) {
          var link = $(this).attr("href");
          $("#product1").load(link);
          event.preventDefault();
        });

        $("#product2 a").click(function() {
          var link = $(this).attr("href");
          $("#product2").load(link);
          return false;
        });
      });
</script>
```

De verdad agradeceria cualquier comentario que me ayude a identificar el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes agregar un evento `click` a cada slide del slider, y dentro del evento podes acceder a los atributos del slide.

Proba con:

`$('.slider').click(function (e) { console.log($('.slider .slick-active').attr("id"))});`

Comment: Gracias @Will Paiz, para complementar, la clase que define el Slider Activo es en realidad `.slick-current` entonces el `.slick-active` es el `id actual menos 1`; sin embargo la lógica es la misma y me funciona. Gracias.